# PHP, adding a key to an array to form a correct SOAP request

Tags: php, arrays, soap, request

I'm trying to make a soap request.
As you can see from the example request, the tag CustomerReferences is reported twice.
In my original PHP request (that works) it's present only the first  tag with the type "CUSTOMER_REFERENCES"

I want to add the second one with the type P_O_NUMBER to an already existing array.

[image]

> ```
>        $parcelinfo = array();
>         $parcelinfo["1"] = array(
>             'SequenceNumber' => 1 + 1,
>             'GroupPackageCount' => 1,
>             'Weight' => array(
>                 'Value' => 10,
>                 'Units' => 20
>             ),
>             'CustomerReferences' => array(
>                 'CustomerReferenceType' => 'CUSTOMER_REFERENCE',
>                 'Value' => 12345
>             )
>         );
> ```

Given this original array, if i do:

> ```
>         $parcelinfo["1"][] = array(
>             'CustomerReferences' => array(
>                 'CustomerReferenceType' => 'P_O_NUMBER',
>                 'Value' => "TESTSKU"
>             )
>         );
> ```

I get the picture below

[image]

How do i add that key to the existing account to comply to the example request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with below array. Notice that **CustomerReferences** is array of array. This will result in two CustomerReference in soap request.

```
$parcelinfo = [
    [
        'SequenceNumber' => 1 + 1,
        'GroupPackageCount' => 1,
        'Weight' => [
            'Value' => 10,
            'Units' => 20
        ],
        'CustomerReferences' => [
            [
                'CustomerReferenceType' => 'CUSTOMER_REFERENCE',
                'Value' => 12345
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

And to add you just do the following

```
$parcelinfo[0]["CustomerReferences"][] = [
                'CustomerReferenceType' => 'P_O_NUMBER',
                'Value' => "This is your po"
            ];
```

Your resulting response is
[image]